# d3.js collapsible force diagram - assigning unique ID's to identical nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a nice Collapsible Force Layout collapsed in the beginning taken from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130.

Here is my example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rqh8SD?p=preview

It works well when all the nodes have unique names (http://plnkr.co/edit/E1n6asBM5VfX2vjGPkKO?p=preview), however as soon as some nodes have the same name (unfortunately I need that), the collapsing does not work properly.

Anyone able to help me assign unique IDs to the identical names of the nodes? I believe this piece of code could make the trick but I do not know where to insert it.

```
node.each(function(d,i){ // use i to iterate through
  d.uniqueID = uniqueNode + i;
}
```

I tried to get this issue solved at my previous thread [D3.js Collapsible Force Layout, collapsed by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813462/d3-js-collapsible-force-layout-collapsed-by-default) - not successful.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like that to make all your nodes unique should work. I'd recommend doing this just after your flatten your nodes, but before you insert them into the Force directed graph:

function update(d) {

```
var nodes = flatten(root),
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

nodes.each(function(d, i) { d.uniqueID = i; });

// Restart the force layout.
force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .start();
```

You'll also need to update your key function when using `.data()` on those nodes

```
  // Update nodes
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.uniqueID; });
```

You need to take note however, that if you change your data that your bindings might be wrong. If you were to insert a new value, then that would push all the indexes off by 1, potentially causing you to data join to the wrong elements in the future.

A possible different way of solving that problem might be to change your key function to look at the ID of the direct parent (or parents) too.